# Passing JSON Through URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have two html files, and the task for us is to pass data between the two. Then I came up with the idea of sending the data through the URL using the hash, and parsing this link something like `JSON.parse(window.location.hash.slice(1));` and assigning it to a local variable. It seems to work for the couple try. But when I populated my JS files with codes error occurs. Can you tell what alternative can I do.? Here's the console errors. I'm using jquery by the way ..

[The Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KV4w.png)

Thank you!

Comment: The error looks like you're trying to use the JSON in a jQuery selector and it contains a lot of invalid characters which you'll need to escape. I'd strongly suggest that you don't send JSON through the URL. Either send a normal querystring, or put the JSON in to `localStorage` and access that on the pages that require the data

Comment: localStorage can hold any type of data right.?

Comment: That's right. You could store the object itself directly in localStorage which will save you having to serialise/deserialise it

Comment: If you use localStorage consider using Argon to make storing and retrieving the data easier https://github.com/geuis/argon

Comment: @mer igos No everything is serialized to a string. One reason I wrote Argon was to avoid that problem

Comment: I'll consider using your work sir geuis ^_^

Comment: localStorage is the best way to access data anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

JSON contains a number of characters that are not legal in urls.

A simple way around this could be to simply encode the JSON data using Base64.

Comment: Is that compatible to all browser.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest way of accessing the data from one page to another:

//1st page

```
storage["key"]=data;
```

//2nd page

```
var value= storage["key"];
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `storage["key"]=data;` is that built in in JS.? Sorry for being so new ..

Comment: yes, data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the browsing session ends.

Comment: i would prefer you to use this and it supports all browsers.

Comment: So storage means localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery.param is what you need it converts a Json into a URL String

http://www.sourcecodemart.com/convert-json-object-to-url-query-string/

Answer (score 0):

This won't work in the long run. urls are limited to about 2000 characters. [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

You have to base64 encode the json to have it live in the URL. This eats up a lot of the available characters.

You don't get the same limitations when doing POST requests but a HTML page can't access post requests.

You might want to look at postMessage and embedding one page in the other in an iframe to do cross communication.

Also if the urls are on the same domain, just use local or session storage.